# closed form for number of partial orders on an n-element set

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a known closed form formula for the number of partial orders on an n-element set? I have checked other questions like this, but they do not have a closed form formula.

Comment: This might help ... https://oeis.org/A000112

Comment: I don't know of a closed form ... but there are recursive methods to construct them ... look in the references in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. However, a lower bound is available, regarding the number of partial orders $P_n$ on an $n$-set, it is known that $$P_n\geq {2^\frac{n^2}{4}}$$